# Why last id is lost while creating process?

Tags: laravel, eloquent

I have a create method that works fine, but it fails trying to create its relation:

```
public function create(array $article, string $note)
{
    $art = $this->article->create($article);

    print($art->id) // this line is for helping me to know if id is successfully generated. It works!

    $this->article->note()->create([
        'article_id' => $art->id, // the id desapears
        'note'       => $note
    ])
}
```

Console logs:

> Integrity constraint violation: 1048 Column 'article_id' cannot be null (SQL: insert into `notes` (`article_id`, `note`, `updated_at`, `created_at`) values (?, TESTING, 2019-11-13 13:03:07, 2019-11-13 13:03:07))"

Comment: What returns dd($art);?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The field `article_id` is probably not a [fillable attribute](https://laravel.com/docs/6.x/eloquent#mass-assignment) on the `Note` model.

You could also create the note like this, without adding `article_id` as a fillable attribute:

```php
$art->note()->create([
    'note' => $note
]);
```

Also make sure that the relations are defined correctly on the models. If an article can have many notes, there might be something wrong with your definitions, since `note` is currently singular. If it is a one to one relation everything might be fine.

Answer (score 0):

You need to save your article. `$art->save()`